# generate a new average price all the time when I input a product in stock

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm new on this website, and not aware of how to post a question, so please be patient with me.

I do not know hot to generate in excel a new average price all the time when I add a product in stock. I want to keep the old average price and when I add the same product in stock (is the same product but the price is not the same) to generate a new average price (price/quantity) form the old average price and new average price/2. will be the average price from the new and old price. It is possible? **The average price is per kg that means the price is divided by the quantity.**

Thank you!

I generated the average price for the products added in stock. also I have average price between 2 dates but I need to make static the old average price all the time when I add a product in stock and to generate another one.

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OaPL.png)

Comment: Can you give us a sample of data to work from and what you think it should look like as an end result?

Comment: You can familiarize youself with how this site works by taking the [Two Minute Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @SaintFrag I tried to make a sample . see the pic

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table like this:

| Date | Item | Price | Qty | Avg Price | Rolling Average Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | Widget | 1 | 100 | 0.01 |  |
| 3/1/2023 | Gizmo | 50 | 20 | 2.5 |  |
| 3/13/2023 | Widget | 1.5 | 100 | 0.02 |  |
| 3/13/2023 | Gizmo | 49 | 21 | 2.33 |  |
| 7/1/2023 | Widget | 1.51 | 150 | 0.01 |  |
| 9/21/2023 | Gizmo | 48 | 20 | 2.4 |  |

Then in the **Rolling Average Price** column, you can use this formula:

```
=AVERAGEIFS([Avg Price],[Item],[@Item],[Date],"<="&[@Date])
```

This does NOT give only the two most recent prices, but I'm not sure if that was your intent or not.

*Updated for new information.

Comment: The average price is per kg that means the price is divided by the quantity. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OaPL.png

Comment: You might try using a SORT or SORT and FILTER combo but I'm not familiar enough with those to guide you.  I believe you'd have to use them in combination with ROW to get the sort to work based on order of entry.  Assuming you're planning on adding rows to the table on the left.  Otherwise:  Create your function in the table on the right, and copy/paste as values to keep your statics.